# Change Address Range Windows VPN

Tags: windows, vpn, address

I am wondering how to change the Address Range for the VPN connections on Windows RRAS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your RRAS server is obtaining IP addresses from DHCP then you'll be changing the DHCP scope from which the addresses are obtained. You can see this setting on the "IP" tab of the properties of the RRAS server in the Routing and Remote Access management console.

If your RRAS server is using a server-assigned pool of addresses, change the range specified on that same "IP" tab.